# How to embed macros in rule type text with Stanford Token regex

Tags: macros, stanford-nlp

I am struggling to involve macro in ruleType: "text". Is it possible to do it?

What I've tried so far:

```
$BasicOrdinal = "\d{1,2}\s?(st|nd|rd|th)"
ENV.defaults["stage"] = 0

{
   ruleType: "text",
   pattern:  /($BasicOrdinal)\s*-?\s*quarter/,
   result: "QUARTER"
}
```

and I get blank results.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try a rule file like this example:

```
ner = { type: "CLASS", value: "edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$NamedEntityTagAnnotation" }

$BASIC_ORDINAL = "/[0-9]+(rd|th)/"

{ pattern: ($BASIC_ORDINAL /quarter/), action: (Annotate($0, ner, "QUARTER") ) }
```